# I optimized my server but still can't go over 500 Requests per second on ApacheBench

Tags: php, apache, optimization, amazon-ec2

I am using:

- EC2 c4.2xlarge (16 CPU , 32 GB RAM)
- RDS MYSQL database db.m4.2xlarge
- Amazon linux
- apache 2.4
- php 5.5
- Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev

/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf is as follow

```
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
StartServers 100
MinSpareServers 100
MaxSpareServers 200
ServerLimit 2000
MaxClients 2000
MaxRequestsPerChild 0
```

when i stress test with

```
ab -t 30 -c 2000
```

I get the following:

---

```
Document Path:          /
Document Length:        46135 bytes

Concurrency Level:      2000
Time taken for tests:   30.006 seconds
Complete requests:      15333
Failed requests:        2
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 2, Exceptions: 0)
Write errors:           0
Non-2xx responses:      2
Total transferred:      717478783 bytes
HTML transferred:       707298139 bytes
Requests per second:    511.00 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       3913.883 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1.957 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          23350.93 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0  260 1261.9      0   15035
Processing:    19 1466 3797.3    229   26242
Waiting:       18 1465 3797.3    228   26236
Total:         19 1726 4323.8    232   29231

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    232
  66%    520
  75%   2046
  80%   2109
  90%   4098
  95%   7536
  98%  20550
  99%  26805
 100%  29231 (longest request)
```

---

the 16 CPUs do not go over 40%
and the used RAM is maxed at 4GB
The website is a custom Ecomerce application using codeigniter

My question is why I am still stuck with a maximum of 500 Requests per second while using a powerful server ?

THank you

Comment: Apache is quite a bottleneck itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t think there is an absolute answer based on the results you provided. You have to find the bottleneck by measuring local and remote resource consumption, e.g. cpu, network, memory.

I assume you called the starting-page of your application. That might not be the most efficient page as it has to load resources, start session etc. so what you got may actually be quite ok.

Comment: Most of the 16 CPUs are used to a maximum of 40 %
and used RAM does not go over 4 GB !!

Comment: So its like the server still has resources to spare. Did you variate your test to include more/less clients or maybe a different landing page, e.g. just static html ?